# Error in build the wheel when installing the Python package?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, deep-learning, pip

I am trying to install psqlparse package on my system, but it is giving me wheel build error.
I tried these methods to install and they all give the same error.

```
*#1 use pip*
pip install psqlparse==1.0rc7

*#2 use pip*
pip install -U psqlparse==1.0rc7

*#3 use setup.py*
python setup.py install
```

> **Error:**

```
Collecting psqlparse==1.0rc7
  Using cached psqlparse-1.0rc7.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\soha\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from psqlparse==1.0rc7) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: psqlparse
  Building wheel for psqlparse (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      c:\users\soha\appdata\local\programs\python\python375\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:529: UserWarning: Normalizing '1.0-rc7' to '1.0rc7'
        warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse
      copying psqlparse\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse
      copying psqlparse\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\nodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\parsenodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\primnodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\value.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      running build_ext
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psqlparse
  Running setup.py clean for psqlparse
Failed to build psqlparse
Installing collected packages: psqlparse
  Running setup.py install for psqlparse ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for psqlparse did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      c:\users\soha\appdata\local\programs\python\python375\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:529: UserWarning: Normalizing '1.0-rc7' to '1.0rc7'
        warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
      running install
      c:\users\soha\appdata\local\programs\python\python375\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. U
se build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse
      copying psqlparse\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse
      copying psqlparse\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\nodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\parsenodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\primnodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\value.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      copying psqlparse\nodes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\psqlparse\nodes
      running build_ext
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> psqlparse
```

This package is easily installed by the second installation method i.e. "pip install -U psqlparse==1.0rc7" in google colab, but I am facing problems to install it in my system. I really need this package.
My system: Windows 10 64bit

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: It seems like this library is not compatible with Windows: https://github.com/alculquicondor/psqlparse/issues/30

Comment: Also from here [psqlparse](https://github.com/alculquicondor/psqlparse); *This project is not maintained anymore* . The last code update was almost 3 1/2 years ago. You might want to look at [pglast](https://github.com/lelit/pglast) which is current and uses the same underlying library `libpg_query`.